# React child state doesn't get updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent component that initializes the state using hooks. I pass in the state and setState of the hook into the child, but whenever I update the state in multiple children they update the state that is not the most updated one.

**To reproduce problem**: when you make a link and write in your info and click submit, it successfully appends to the parent state. If you add another one after that, it also successfully appends to the parent state. But when you go back and press submit on the first link, it destroys the second link for some reason. Please try it out on my codesandbox.

Basically what I want is a button that makes a new form. In each form you can select a social media type like fb, instagram, tiktok, and also input a textfield. These data is stored in the state, and in the end when you click apply changes, I want it to get stored in my database which is firestore. Could you help me fix this? Here is a code sandbox on it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fog-oz10p

and here is my code:

Admin.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import AddNewLink from './AddNewLink';

const Admin = () => {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState({});
  const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState([]);

  const updateLinks = (socialMedia, url) => { 
    setLinks({
      ...links,
      [socialMedia]: url
    })
  }

  const linkData = {
    links,
    updateLinks,
  }
  
  const applyChanges = () => {
    console.log(links);
    // firebase.addLinksToUser(links);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {newLink ? newLink.map(child => child) : null}
      <div className="container-sm">
        <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          setNewLink([ ...newLink, <AddNewLink key={Math.random()} linkData={linkData} /> ])}
        }
      >
        Add new social media
      </Button>
      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{marginTop: '50px'}}
        onClick={() => applyChanges()}
      >
        Apply Changes
      </Button>
      <h3>{JSON.stringify(links, null, 4)}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

AddNewLink.js

```js
const AddNewLink = props => {
  const [socialMedia, setSocialMedia] = useState('');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const { updateLinks } = props.linkData;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    updateLinks(socialMedia, url)
}

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl style={{marginTop: '30px', marginLeft: '35px', width: '90%'}}>
        <InputLabel>Select Social Media</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={socialMedia}
            onChange={e => {setSocialMedia(e.target.value)}}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'facebook'}>Facebook</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'instagram'}>Instagram</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'tiktok'}>TikTok</MenuItem>
          </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <form noValidate autoComplete="off" style={{marginBottom: '30px', marginLeft: '35px'}}>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Enter link" style={{width: '95%'}} onChange={e => {setUrl(e.target.value)}}/>
      </form>
      <div className="container-sm">
        <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{marginBottom: '30px'}}
        onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default AddNewLink;
```

Comment: your codesandbox code does not have all the code...its not working at all.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry my wifi mustve gotten cut off mid way or something. I've updated the codesandbox! Please check it out, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I see is that links in AddNewLink would be a stale closure but in your question you never use it. Here is your code "working" since you didn't describe what it is supposed to do it always "works"

```js
const { useState } = React;

const AddNewLink = (props) => {
  const [socialMedia, setSocialMedia] = useState('');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const { updateLinks, links } = props.linkData;
  console.log('links is a stale closure:', links);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    updateLinks(socialMedia, url);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={socialMedia}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSocialMedia(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="">select item</option>
        <option value={'facebook'}>Facebook</option>
        <option value={'instagram'}>Instagram</option>
        <option value={'tiktok'}>TikTok</option>
      </select>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Enter link"
        style={{ width: '95%' }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setUrl(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{ marginBottom: '30px' }}
        onClick={() => handleSubmit()}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Admin = () => {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState({});
  const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState([]);

  const updateLinks = (socialMedia, url) =>
    setLinks({
      ...links,
      [socialMedia]: url,
    });

  const linkData = {
    links,
    updateLinks,
  };

  const applyChanges = () => {
    console.log(links);
    // firebase.addLinksToUser(links);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {newLink ? newLink.map((child) => child) : null}
      <div className="container-sm">
        <button
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          onClick={() => {
            setNewLink([
              ...newLink,
              <AddNewLink
                key={Math.random()}
                linkData={linkData}
              />,
            ]);
          }}
        >
          Add new social media
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          style={{ marginTop: '50px' }}
          onClick={() => applyChanges()}
        >
          Apply Changes
        </button>
        <h3>{JSON.stringify(links, null, 4)}</h3>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Admin />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It is not a good idea to put jsx in local state, save the data in state instead and pass that to the component every render.